# How to match the car of alist elements with a regexp?

Tags: regular-expressions, association-lists, alists

I've spent a good amount of hours trying to solve this one but without success.
I have an alist with strings

```lisp
(setq trees '(("pine" . "cones") ("oak" . "acorns") ("maple" . "seeds")))
```

and I want to obtain the `assoc` of it using a regexp as key. That is

```lisp
(assoc ".ine" trees)
```

always returns `nil` instead of `("pine" . "cones")`. I've tried to use the assoc-default function instead, using string-match but it also did not work. I know that this is pretty basic, but I cannot really understand what I am doing wrong. Thank you in advance.

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: It's acceptable. It just shouldn't have tag `elisp`. Your question is about *using* Elisp to accomplish something; it's not a question about the nature of the language (e.g. compared to other Lisps).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass a `TESTFN` arg to `assoc`.  It needs to use `string-match-p` with the args reversed.  That is, `assoc` passes `TESTFN` the pattern arg second, but `string-match-p` expects the pattern as its first arg.

```lisp
(assoc ".*ine" trees (lambda (x regexp) (string-match-p regexp x)))
```

---

I filed doc bug report #[50110](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=50110) for this, asking that the arg order for optional arg `TESTFN` be specified.
And that bug has now been fixed!